# React Chart.js Match API data to what Title is displaying, then update chart on data/Title change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have an Title.js that is pulling a title from an API call, from there I am sending it over to TitleCycle.js to Cycle through each job coming from the API call, in this file, I also have the record ID `data[index]['3'].value` which I have displaying under the Job Title for reference (see image) this number relates all records to the job name and also cycles. I've updated my code to show that now I'm looping through whatever api data is in the API call, from here I don't know how to call `{jobId}` from TitleCycle.js in the body of my api call to only get what records are matching the record id when that title changes. Then updates on change with the Title.

Right now, I'm able to put a number in and get the line chart to update accurately with that data. However, instead of having a number I want to pull that from the TitleCycle.js to display whatever Title's Record ID is currently displaying, so it cycles with it.

**Line Chart.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Scatter } from "react-chartjs-2";
import jobId from '../TitleCycle';
// import Title from '../header/Title';

const TotalLineChart = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  const chart = () => {
    let designHours = [];
    let designAmount = [];
    let subRoughHours = [];
    let subRoughAmount = [];
    let roughHours = [];
    let roughAmount = [];
    let finishHours = [];
    let finishAmount = [];
    let closeHours = [];
    let closeAmount = [];
    let actualHours = [];
    let actualAmount = [];

    let headers = {
      "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
      "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
      "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

    let body = {
      from: "bpz99ram7",
      select: [
        3,
        6,
        80,
        81,
        82,
        83,
        86,
        84,
        88,
        89,
        90,
        91,
        92,
        93,
        94,
        95,
        96,
        97,
        98,
        99,
        101,
        103,
        104,
        105,
        106,
        107,
        109,
        111,
        113,
        115,
        120,
        123,
        224,
        225,
        226,
        227,
        228,
        229,
        230,
        231,
        477,
        479,
        480,
        481
      ],
      where: "{3.EX. '290'}", // this is where i'm attempting to place {jobId}, right now it is set to 290 manually, thats where the data is coming from in the images below. ONLY EFFECTING TOP LINE CHART!
      sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
      groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
      options: { skip: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false }
    };

    fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }) 
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log({jobId})
        Object.keys(res.data).map(jobId => {
          const designHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['88'].value, 10);
          const designAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['91'].value, 10);
          const subRoughHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['92'].value, 10);
          const subRoughAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['95'].value, 10);
          const roughHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['96'].value, 10);
          const roughAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['98'].value, 10);
          const finishHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['104'].value, 10);
          const finishAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['107'].value, 10);
          const closeHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['477'].value, 10);
          const closeAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['480'].value, 10);
          const actualHours = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['479'].value, 10);
          const actualAmount = parseInt(res.data[jobId]['224'].value, 10);

          setChartData({
            type: 'scatter',
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: 'TOTAL',
                  data: [
                    { x: designHours, y: designAmount },
                    { x: subRoughHours, y: subRoughAmount },
                    { x: roughHours, y: roughAmount },
                    { x: finishHours, y: finishAmount },
                    { x: closeHours, y: closeAmount }
                  ],
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: '#4183c4',
                  backgroundColor: '#4183c4',
                  tension: 0.8,
                  spanGaps: true,
                  lineTension: 0.5,
                  showLine: true,
                  fill: false,
                  showTooltip: false,
                  pointBorderWidth: 1
                },
                {
                  label: 'ACTUALS',
                  data: [{ x: actualHours, y: actualAmount }],
                  fill: false,
                  borderColor: '#e34747',
                  backgroundColor: '#e34747',
                  borderWidth: 5,
                  showTooltip: false
                }
              ],
              options: {
                showAllTooltips: true,
                enabled: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                  display: true
                }
              }
          });
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(
      designHours,
      designAmount,
      subRoughHours,
      subRoughAmount,
      roughHours,
      roughAmount,
      finishHours,
      finishAmount,
      closeHours,
      closeAmount,
      actualHours,
      actualAmount
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Scatter
          data={chartData}
          options={{
            responsive: true,
            title: { text: "Total Project", display: true },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Dollar Amounts'
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 10,
                    beginAtZero: true
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Hours'
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TotalLineChart;
```

*Note the comment above to show where I'm trying to place `{jobId}` from TitleCycle.js ONLY EFFECTING TOP LINE CHART*
*Attempted to change API body to: `where: "{3.EX. '{jobId}'}",`

**TitleCycle.js**

```
import React from "react";

function TitleCycle({ data }) {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const jobId = data[index]['3'].value;

  // Set Timer and Interval based on Index
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
      () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % data.length),
      5000 // 5 seconds.
    );
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [data]);
console.log(data[index]['3'].value)
  return data.length ? (
    <div className="TitleCycle">
      <h3>{data[index]["6"].value}</h3>
      {jobId}
    </div>
  ) : null;
}

export default TitleCycle;
```

**Title.js**

```
import { Component, React } from "react";
import TitleCycle from '../TitleCycle';
//import TotalLineChart from '../charts/TotalLineChart'

let headers = {
  "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
  "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
  "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

class Title extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,40],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}};

    fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({data}) => this.setState({ data }));
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    if (data === null) return "Loading...";

    return (
      <div className="Title">
        <TitleCycle data={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Title;
```

*Note this is only sending the Job Name over to TitleCycle.js as {data}*
[image]
**Above you can see a job name, with the record ID below, which Cycles with the job on a set duration**
[image]
**Above you can see how it changed and updated the record ID, So now I just want that field of `{jobId}` to be able to be set in my LineChart.js file so that the data being pulled is whatever data is displaying**

ONLY THE TOP LINE CHART IS BEING EFFECTED RIGHT NOW, this is where I'm attempting this first before changing the others to match.
Hope this helps!

**App.js**

```
import './App.css'
// import Title from './components/header/Title'
import TotalLineChart from './components/charts/TotalLineChart'
import RadiantLineChart from './components/charts/RadiantLineChart'
import PlumbingLineChart from './components/charts/PlumbingLineChart'
import SnowmeltLineChart from './components/charts/SnowmeltLineChart'
import HVACLineChart from './components/charts/HVACLineChart'
import GasPipeLineChart from './components/charts/GasPipeLineChart'
import FixturesLineChart from './components/charts/FixturesLineChart'
// import JobsTableApi from './components/JobsTableApi'
import ClassBudgetsTableApi from './components/ClassBudgetsTableApi'
// import TitleCycle from './components/TitleCycle'
import Title from './components/header/Title'
// import Logo from './components/Logo';
// import CurrentTitleInfo from './components/CurrentTitleInfo'

function App() {

  return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="flexbox-container">
          <div className="Logo">

         {/* </div> */}
                     {/* <Logo /> */}
          <div className="App">
            <Title />
          </div>
        {/* </div> */}
        <div className="TopChart">
          <TotalLineChart />
        </div>
        <div className="FirstRowContainer">
          <RadiantLineChart />
          <PlumbingLineChart />
          <FixturesLineChart />
        </div>
        <div className="SecondRowContainer">
          <SnowmeltLineChart />
          <HVACLineChart />
          <GasPipeLineChart />
        </div> 
        {/* <JobsTableApi /> */}
        <ClassBudgetsTableApi />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Update**
**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.css'
import Title from './components/header/Title'
import TotalLineChart from './components/charts/TotalLineChart'
import RadiantLineChart from './components/charts/RadiantLineChart'
import PlumbingLineChart from './components/charts/PlumbingLineChart'
import SnowmeltLineChart from './components/charts/SnowmeltLineChart'
import HVACLineChart from './components/charts/HVACLineChart'
import GasPipeLineChart from './components/charts/GasPipeLineChart'
import FixturesLineChart from './components/charts/FixturesLineChart'
// import TitleCycle from './components/TitleCycle'
// import Logo from './components/Logo';

let headers = {
  "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
  "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
  "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXXX",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);

  // Fetch all data, all jobs
  useEffect(() => {
      function fetchData() {
          let body = {
              from: "bpz99ram7",
              select: [3, 6, 40],
              where: "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}",
              sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
              groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
              options: { skip: 0, top: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false },
          };

          fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: headers,
              body: JSON.stringify(body),
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(({ data }) => setAllData(data));
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);

// Cycle through the jobIds and indexes
useEffect(() => {
  const timerId = setInterval(
      () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % allData.length),
      5000 // 5 seconds.
  );
  return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, [allData]);

  // Calculate info based on index
  const jobId = allData[index]["3"].value;
  const title = allData[index]["6"].value;

  return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="flexbox-container">
          <div className="Logo">
          {/* <Logo /> */}
         {/* </div> */}
        <div className="App">
          <Title title = {title}/>
        </div>
        <div className="TopChart">
          <TotalLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
        </div>
        <div className="FirstRowContainer">
          <RadiantLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <PlumbingLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <FixturesLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
        </div>
        <div className="SecondRowContainer">
          <SnowmeltLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <HVACLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
          <GasPipeLineChart jobId = {jobId}/>
        </div> 
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined*

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 316
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "1545 Indian Hills"
      },
      "40": {
        "value": "In Progress"
      }
    },
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 291
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "1547 Tomahawk"
      },
      "40": {
        "value": "In Progress"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to sync the `jobId` state between the TitleCycle component and the LineChart component, so that both has access to this variable, and can render stuff in sync (Title changes and LineChart changes also).

In that case, you need `jobId` as a somewhat global variable. I think of this solution.

This seems to be the current hierachy

```
App
|-- LineChart
|-- Title
    |-- TitleCycle
```

Therefore, put the `jobId` in the common ancestor and prop drills it down. In this case, instead of generating `jobId` and `index` from TitleCycle and having to lift the state back up and around into LineChart, you shall cycle the indexes right inside App.js. Something like this:

```
// App.js
function App() {
    const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    // Fetch all data, all jobs
    useEffect(() => {
        function fetchData() {
            let body = {
                from: "bpz99ram7",
                select: [3, 6, 40],
                where: "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}",
                sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
                groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
                options: { skip: 0, top: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false },
            };

            fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then(({ data }) => setAllData(data));
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    // Cycle through the jobIds and indexes
    useEffect(() => {
        const timerId = setInterval(
            () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % allData.length),
            5000 // 5 seconds.
        );
        return () => clearInterval(timerId);
    }, [allData]);

    // Calculate info based on index
    const jobId = allData[index]?.["3"]?.value || "290"; // Default "290"
    const title = allData[index]?.["6"]?.value || "Default title"; 

    // Renders the components with the necessary data
    return (
        <div>
            <Title title={title} />
            <LineChart1 jobId={jobId} />
            <LineChart2 jobId={jobId} />
        </div>
    );
}

// LineChart.js
function TotalLineChart(props) {
    // Got the jobId from props
    const { jobId } = props;

    // Now make the request with this jobId
}
```

Comment: So you are saying to do this in App.js? And then for each line chart, still do same as in my Question?

Comment: Yes. What I am saying is having a central place to store data (App.js). If any line chart needs this `jobId`, the App.js will provide it to them. Then the line charts can do what ever with this `jobId`. By having `jobId` at a central place, everything is in sync.

Comment: Ok. I will give this a shot in my code. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: How would you recommend me go about including the other line charts to match that jobId? their api calls are different, and the matching field is not '3' but '20'. '3' is the jobId for the Title and TotalLineChart, the others to match to are '20'. if that makes sense

Comment: Actually never mind, if I'm following correctly, I can still send ```{jobId}``` to these other line charts, and in the API body, just specify ```where: "20.EX. '{jobId}'" ``` to say if that field has that ID.

Comment: Bao, getting an error with '3', updated code to show current App.js

Comment: Oh sorry that is my bad. On the initial mount, `allData` is just an empty array (data has not been fetched yet) - therefore `jobId` and `title` cannot be calculated. I have editted my App.js to use default values when `allData` has not been filled. Check it out, and replace these default values to your liking.

Comment: Ok I see, I wonder why it's not fetching? If I console.log allData I get all the info needed, but then if I try to change back to get the values of what job is displaying, it goes to undefined.

Comment: Also, even if I try to use the default, I'm unable to use {jobId} in my body of the linechart api call, to call whatever id that is coming from app.js. ```const { jobId } = props;``` declared but never used, ```where: "{3.EX. '{jobId}'}" ```

Comment: If you want to "inject" a variable onto your string, you should use [JS template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). So, change to `\`{3.EX. ${jobId}}\``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234289/discussion-between-bao-huynh-lam-and-alexb801).